# Is Item typemapping=query still needed in Web 8 storage configuration?

Tags: web8, configuration

We're upgrading from Tridion 2011 to Web 8.5. We've noticed that on the 2011 system we need to declare `<Item typeMapping="Query" .../>` in order to have our queries work. On the Web 8 system it appears to work fine without it.

I can imagine that this configuration option was eventually seen as unnecessary (who wouldn't want queries?)

Has this been removed? Is it safe to proceed without it?

Comment: if it works... not sure what this question is about :)

Comment: @Nuno - at least in part because without "permission" to remove a setting like this, there's a likelihood it will still be polluting the config in years to come.